# Getting jboss ejb in ativemq rar deployed within jboss

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jndi, naming

I have an activemq broker deployed within my jboss server. 
activemq is deployed as a rar file placed in jboss standalone/deployment repository. 
An other project is also deployed within my jboss as an ear file.
This last is exposing some ejb objects in my jboss. 
I tried to get an ejb from a jar file that I put into my activemq rar file. A class placed within the jar is called when I connect a client to the broker.

**This is how I tried to get ejb within jar file:**

```
  Context ctx; 
  Properties jndiProps = new Properties(); 
  jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming"); 
  jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true); 
  ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps); 
  Ctx.lookup("ejb:Hemis/HemisCoreClient//"+ "HardwareDataManagement" + "!" + "com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement");
```

**Log from jboss when ejb is exposed:**

*11:50:17,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named HardwareDataManagement in deployment unit subdeployment "HemisCoreClient.jar" of deployment "Hemis.ear" are as follows:

java:global/Hemis/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement 
  java:app/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement 
  java:module/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement 
  java:jboss/exported/Hemis/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement 
  java:global/Hemis/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement 
  java:app/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement 
  java:module/HardwareDataManagement*

**The log error when I try to connect client to the broker:**

*17:26:15,555 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'java:Hemis/HemisCoreClient//HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement' 
17:26:15,556 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:490) 
17:26:15,557 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:536) 
17:26:15,557 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) 
17:26:15,558 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at authentification.TokenAuthentificationBroker.addConnection(TokenAuthentificationBroker.java:46) 
17:26:15,558 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConnection(MutableBrokerFilter.java:97) 
17:26:15,558 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:733) 
17:26:15,559 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79) 
17:26:15,559 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139) 
17:26:15,560 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292) 
17:26:15,561 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:149) 
17:26:15,562 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83) 
17:26:15,562 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.MQTTSocket.sendToActiveMQ(MQTTSocket.java:112) 
17:26:15,563 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.sendToActiveMQ(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:133) 
17:26:15,564 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTConnect(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:235) 
17:26:15,564 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTCommand(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:157) 
17:26:15,566 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.MQTTSocket.onMessage(MQTTSocket.java:59) 
17:26:15,566 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455$WSFrameHandler.onFrame(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:860) 
17:26:15,567 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketParserRFC6455.parseNext(WebSocketParserRFC6455.java:349) 
17:26:15,568 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:225) 
17:26:15,568 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628) 
17:26:15,569 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) 
17:26:15,571 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) 
17:26:15,571 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) 
17:26:15,572 ERROR [stderr] (qtp1869699331-251) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)*

**How could I resolve this?  Could someone help me?**

Comment: Try this JNDI lookup? `java:global/Hemis/HemisCoreClient/HardwareDataManagement!com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement `

Comment: I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Is this double splash made on purpose? `Ctx.lookup("ejb:Hemis/HemisCoreClient//"+ "HardwareDataManagement" + "!" + "com.ubiant.hemis.client.ejb.interf.I_HardwareDataManagement")`. On the issue of JNDI lookup, you should have had resourceRef in the xml discriptor which provide the global friendly naming rather than refering to vendor specific JNDI name.

Comment: I would suggest using a JNDI browser tool and look into the enviroment to check the correct path.

Comment: I think that I am getting this problem because I am trying to get ejb from rar file deployed inti jboss. Because I tried to get ejb from the ear which is exposing the ejb and it works. I don't know how to resolve this problem

Comment: In the .rar module, don't you have a deployment descriptor there, ra.xml? Do you not exposing any other resources there? Maybe this artical will help https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Configure_a_Deployed_Resource_Adapter1.html.

Comment: Yes I have a ra.xml file in addition to ironjacamar.xml file and I am exposing other resources related to activemq.